# regex lookbehind in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

i im trying to match some words in text

working example (what i want) [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yC2lY7/2):

```
regex = /(?<![a-z])word/g
text = word 1word !word aword
```

only the first three words will be matched which is what i want to achieve.
but the look behind will not work in javascript :(

so now im trying this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fH9iL2/1):

```
regex = /(\b|\B)word/g
text = word 1word !word aword
```

but all words will match and they may not be preceded with an other letter, only with an integer or special characters.
if i use only the smaller "\b" the 1word wont matchand if i only use the "\B" the !word will not match

**Edit**

The output should be ["word","word","word"]

and the 1 ! must not be included in the match also not in another group, this is because **i want to use it with javascript .replace(regex,function(match){})** which should not loop over the 1 and !

**The code** i use it for

```
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    text = elements[i].innerHTML;

    textnew = text.replace(regexp,function(match){
        matched = getCrosslink(match)[0];
        return "<a href='"+matched.url+"'>"+match+"</a>";
    });
    elements[i].innerHTML = textnew;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: the first three "word" must match and not the last one (aword)

Comment: What do you plan to do with the first three words after you match them?

Comment: i will wrap them with some html tags <a> for example

Comment: What is the exact definition of what you want to match? Match the first three? Match `"word"` when it is not preceded by a letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Capturing the leading character**

It's difficult to know exactly what you want without seeing more output examples, but what about looking for either starts with boundary *or* starts with a non-letter. Like this for example:

```
(\bword|[^a-zA-Z]word)
```

Output: `['word', '1word', '!word']`

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/eU6uR6/2)

---

**Capturing only the "word"**

If you only want the "word" part to be captured you can use the following and fetch the 2nd capture group:

```
(\b|[^a-zA-Z])(word)
```

Output: `['word', 'word', 'word']`

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/vF4qC7/2)

---

**With replace()**

You can use specific capture groups when defining the replace value, so this will work for you (where `"new"` is the word you want to use):

```
var regex = /(\b|[^a-zA-Z])(word)/g;
var text = "word 1word !word aword";

text = text.replace(regex, "$1" + "new");
```

output: `"new 1new !new aword"`

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/0rrzp0sm/)

If you are using a dedicated function in replace, try this:

```
textnew = text.replace(regexp,function (allMatch, match1, match2){
    matched = getCrosslink(match2)[0];
    return "<a href='"+matched.url+"'>"+match2+"</a>";
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/0rrzp0sm/1/)

Comment: the 1 and ! are still matched in an other group, and this won't work with javascripts .replace() function cause i will also loop over the 1 and !

Comment: @77120: You didn't say you needed to use in a replace function, only get matches

Comment: Im afraid i have to tell a little more about my code :), im using the replace function like this text.replace(regex,function(match){});

Comment: @77120: Ok sorted, you can specify multiple params to get each capture group. See edit

Comment: Aah thanks a lot, it works :). couldn't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @77120: No worries, glad we got there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex

```
([^a-zA-Z]|\b)(word)
```

Simply use `replace` like as

```
var str = "word 1word !word aword";
str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z]|\b)(word)/g,"$1"+"<a>$2</a>");
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/cD0wQ1/1)

Comment: almost :), but now the 1 and ! are included in the match

Comment: so you only need to extract only `word` and not the `1word` & `!word`

Comment: For me, `word 1word !word aword".match(/([^a-zA-Z]|\b)(word)/)` gives `["word", "", "word"]`.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1hvxu3a/) kind of built on this answer.

Comment: Or [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1hvxu3a/1/) that adds an arbitrary digit to the word to *prove* that the correct word is extracted.

Comment: Updated my answer @77120

Comment: Thanks for the update, i think it almost works for me but i had to make another update to my question, because i use .replace(regexp,function(match) and im not sure how to use the $1 in that case